# How to check if the string is in proper array format with regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, regex-group

I want to check if the string is proper array structure for example:

```
"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"
```

I want regex that should match square brackets at the start `[` and end `]` and within square brackets, it should only contain the digits `0-9` and comma `,`. Same as like above *i.e. array of digits but it's a string*.

I tried the following:

```
/\[\d+\]/
```

But it's not working for commas `,`.

**Edited:**

I am receiving `"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"` as a string from `POST` method.

Comment: Use `/^\[\d+(?:,\d+)*]$/`

Comment: returns `true` for `[0123456789]`.

Comment: why not `is_array()` ?

Comment: No any digit, not single sir. Actually I just want a proper array structure regex match. that's all for example `"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"`.

Comment: A digit can only be single. A number can be made of multiple digits.

Comment: You cannot use a regex to match numbers incremented by 1 after a comma. You will need to use `/^\[(\d+(?:,\d+)*)]$/` and upon a match explode Group 1 value and use some code to see if the numbers increment consecutively.

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe cast it to array?

Comment: I will only cast it to an array if it fits the requirements i-e `"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"`, if it is `"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,"` then casting will cause runtine error.

Comment: Why not `try-catch`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew!!! Bad solution, no need to do extra lines of codes as in the link above for a little match. The answer worked. Thanks to all guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously not regex at all, but you'll end up with the array of ints you want, and no runtime errors.

```
if (is_array($array = json_decode($string)) && array_filter($array, 'is_int') == $array) {
    // $string is a properly formatted array of ints, now in $array. Do stuff with it
} else {
    // $string is something else, return an error or whatever
}
```

Comment: Would a triple `===` not be a better idea?

Comment: @TagBot in this case I don't think it would make a difference. If any non-int is filtered out, the arrays won't even be the same length, and the loose comparison will definitely catch that.

Comment: I could only find single failing test case: `'[01]'`, but I guess it is not that important.

Comment: @TagBot good point! I suppose it depends on the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was already answered, but in case someone may need this regex for a different purpose, you can use `^\[([0-9]|.+(,[0-9])+)\]$`

**Quick explanation:**

1. Your input must contain only digits between 0 - 9 `[0-9]` that can be separated with `,` and each `,` must be followed by another digit `[0-9]` which can be expressed like this: `[0-9]|.+(,[0-9])`
2. All digits must be inside square brackets starting with [ and ending with ] and since square brackets are special characters in regex, so we need to escape them: `\[`    and `\]`

You can test this expression at https://regex101.com/

Comment: This is matching `[ljhfs*ù$"&,0,1]`